# symfony2 tinymce doesn't shows up

Tags: symfony, tinymce

i ve installed the bundle  stfalcon/tinymce-bundle and i followed the doc (https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle), I have a `<textarea class = "tinymce"></textarea>` 
 , but when i put  `{{ tinymce_init() }}` into my template, there is nothing. 
But when i press CTRL+U i can see that the JS files are loaded (from web folder). There is no exception, just nothing besides my html textarea.
I've been on the web for hours but no solution is working for me.

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Hard to help without being there. Have you checked if the scripts are actually loaded in the Network Tab of the developer tools of your browser? If I'm not mistaken CTRL+U is only the source code of the website. Perhaps you missed the "assets:install" and the scripts are not loaded?

Comment: I will see, but its supposed to launch an exception if the files  are missing no? thanks

Comment: I don't know what browser you are using to debug. I use chrome and CTRL+U brings up the source, whereas F12 brings up the developer tools on which I can check the network tab for failures related to assets not being loaded. It also shows an exception in the console.

Comment: Do you have ```{% javascripts ... %}``` and ```{% stylesheets %}``` in your twig layout template ?

Comment: What version of Symfony2 are you running ? Do you use jQuery ? Did you install the assets (php app/console assets:install web/) ?

Comment: @Marcel Burkhard  I dont have `{% stylesheets %}` in this template, stysheet is included from another template.
@Tom Toms i have sf 2.3 and yes i installed the asset via this command

Comment: ahah thanks Tom toms! your jquery question makes me realise that jquery version of tinymce was on "false". Put it on true and it works now!